# Reboot in Recovery Android

Tags: android, recovery, reboot

I've finally managed to get the Reboot code work. I used following code :

```
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = null;
        OutputStreamWriter osw = null;
        StringBuilder sbstdOut = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder sbstdErr = new StringBuilder();

        String command="/system/bin/reboot";

        try { // Run Script

            proc = runtime.exec("su");
            osw = new OutputStreamWriter(proc.getOutputStream());
                                osw.write(command);
                    osw.flush();
            osw.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (osw != null) {
                try {
                    osw.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();                    
                }
            }
        }
        try {
            if (proc != null)
                proc.waitFor();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        sbstdOut.append(ReadBufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc
                .getInputStream())));
        sbstdErr.append(ReadBufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc
                .getErrorStream())));
        if (proc.exitValue() != 0) {
                    }
```

Now I want a code that will reboot the device into recovery mode. The application will be only for Samsung Galaxy S. I didn't found any code for reboot in recovery, is there any way to reboot in recovery via code?

Answer (score 1):

If the version of the reboot command and the backend it calls on that device supports it, this may work:

```
String command="/system/bin/reboot recovery";
```

Realize of course that the minute you use the su program you are playing with unsupported modifications of android.

Comment: Like Chris said above, but I would write it as `su -c reboot recovery` as `su` is already defined in the Android system path so you don't need to provide the full path of the app.

Comment: @Chuong - No.  This code executes a 'su' process and pipes command input into it, because the 'su' hacks do not all accept a command to execute from the command line.  As 'su' is already running when the command string is piped in, you do not want to include 'su' again in the commands.  Further, when executing things as root, you do not want to trust path settings which could have been altered by an attacker, but rather explicitly specify the target executable.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the OP can just run the command I provided above in one step, as opposed to activating `su` then run a worker process like `/system/bin/reboot recovery`. Either way would work for the OP. :)

Comment: @Chuong - **no, they cannot in the general case**.  As you'd see if you spent some time reading similar questions, only *some* of the 'su' hacks allow you to specify a command and its arguments to run on the command line, while others require that you pipe the command and arguments into the process after it starts.  Remember that an application-user accessable 'su' is **not part of Android**, but rather a **non-standard** aftermarket hack.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you not using:

((PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE)).reboot("recovery");

?
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#reboot%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: This api requires the REBOOT (android.permission.REBOOT) permission.  According to this permission's declaration (in frameworks/base/core/res/AndroidManifest.xml), its protectionLevel is 'signature'.  That is to say, the apk of the app using this api should be signed with the same certificate as the app declared the permission, namely 'framework-res'.  If the certificates signed it is not available, it's more difficult to achive this without using '/system/bin/reboot'.