# android recovery through scripting

Tags: android, recovery, reboot

Is there any way to reboot and restore a backup ROM automatically?

Currently I am using CWM recovery.

I can reboot into recovery through the app already (pretty much the same steps described here: [Reboot in Recovery Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111539/reboot-in-recovery-android)).

However, once it goes into the CWM recovery interface I have no way of controlling it.  What I am looking for is when it reboots into recovery, it will select a predefined restore image and start restoring from it.  This in effect will wipe all data on the phone and reset it to a predefined state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well you could use Team Win Recovery Projects's (TWRP) OpenRecoveryScript...

scripting options available: http://www.teamw.in/OpenRecoveryScript

more info generic TWRP info: http://www.teamw.in/project/twrp2

example of how I have previously used TWRP OpenRecoveryScript's scripting interface: https://github.com/JBirdVegas/android_packages_apps_Settings/blob/jb/src/com/android/settings/liquid/installer/OpenRecoveryScriptSupport.java#L265

CyanogenMod gerrit submission: http://review.cyanogenmod.com/#/c/14650/

While it is possible to check the what recovery was last booted, I do not believe it is possible to query what recovery is installed at runtime.

Comment: Have you actually figured out how to script the ROM installation with TWRP or any other recovery tool?